# Ubuntu Automatically Selects USB to Install to

Tags: usb, drive

When attempting to install Ubuntu, I  selected the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option. This caused Ubuntu to be totally installed on the USB. As I am about to try it again, I see a prompt that says modifications will happen to the "sdb" device. However, that is my USB with the installer on it, not the hard drive. What can I do to change the drive that gets erased and has Ubuntu installed to it?

Edit: The installer does recognize my hard drive in sda because it says "This computer currently has Windows Vista on it. What do you want to do?".

Answer (score 1):

The reason Ubuntu cannot be installed is because it uses a different file system.

You should create a new partition on your hard disk. The new partition should use the "EXT4" file format. You can set this up during the Ubuntu install.

Comment: So if I want to have it on the hard drive, I need to partition it? Is there still a way to wipe it?

Comment: That is correct, 1 partition for Windows (using NTFS) and 1 for Ubuntu (EXT4). Not sure why you want to wipe the disk - this is not mandatory, and will remove your Windows install as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

1. Boot Windows, then run Disk Defragmenter.  If it defragments OK (that is, there's at least 40GB of consecutive free space at the end of the drive), then go to step 2.
2. Install gParted Live on a USB drive, boot off of that and shrink the partition by 40GB (or however much consecutive free space there was).
3. Run the Ubuntu Installer, and tell it to install alongside Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows installation media , use it to format all the partitions . The ubuntu installer will run smoothly then.
Hope this helps.